# If you get a non-secure content warning in IE, how would you determine the cause?

Tags: html, web-services, internet-explorer, networking, web

If you get a non-secure content warning in IE, how would you determine the cause?

And does it matter which version of IE you're using?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the HTTP traffic with a tool like [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) and/or examine your code (right click -> view source). Often, when accessing a page over HTTPS, you'll have resources that attempt to load over HTTP (non-secure), prompting this warning.

The solution is to load all resources over HTTPS when the site is HTTPS.

Additionally, you can force the content to load with the same protocol by prefixing it with a "//". e.g.

```
<img src="//mysite.com/resource.jpg"/>
```